# Angular material md-content - content not scrolling to proper position on input focus

Tags: angularjs, mobile, scroll, focus, angular-material

We got a strange and annoying issue implementing md-toolbar and md-content structure.

its seems that when focusing on element in the lower screen area the screen not scroll to the proper position in order to see the label and the input field.

Removing the md-content container and everything works as accepted, also start typing and data and the now the md-content scroll position is fine again.

Maybe the scroll event got discarded somehow?

In a UI/UX perspective it's a real issue because the user don't understand that he on the requested element and need to scroll the content manually

In order to see it just browse in a mobile device (chrome 51 + Android 4.4.2 in my case) to the default angular material inputs demo and try to focus  on lower level input element.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Any idea / workaround would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to use `md-content`? If it doesn't work don't use it. It is recommended by Angular Material but not necessary in all situations.

Comment: 10x @camden_kid , but in order to support md-toolbar sticky header the content need to be inside md-content.

Comment: What do you mean by "sticky header"? Here's an example of `md-toobar` taken from the docs whith `div` replacing `md-content` - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/GqdEGr

Comment: Fixed header. take a look at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKWrpy and just change the md-content with div and the the toolbar is not fixed anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your last comment see this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VjxryJ?editors=1010)

As I mentioned in my first comment `md-content` can be replaced by `div` when required. The sticky `md-toolbar` is achieved with

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto" flex>
```

Comment: 10x , but still its strange that using the md-content don't trigger focus event. i opened relevant ticket in angular-material github repo

Comment: @EladHirsch Yes, it is strange. I just tried the input demo on my mobile and as you say the view doesn't scroll to the input. The only solution I can think of if you really do want to use `md-content` is to scroll in the code with `$anchorScroll` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll